# Finding unused Security Groups in ec2,rds,LB using boto or bash(using AWS-CLI)

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to find a way to determine orphan security groups so I can clean up and get rid of them. Does anyone know  a way to discover unused security groups. It should check EC2,RDS,LB,VPC etc

I am able to find the unused SG only for EC2 Security groups. I tried to find rds Security groups.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='xxx-xxx-xxx')


sgs = session.client('rds', region_name='us-east-1').describe_db_security_groups()
for sg in sgs:
    print (sg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security Groups are associated with **Elastic Network Interfaces** (ENIs).

Therefore, you could iterate through all ENIs and retrieve the attached Security Groups. Then, compare the list against security groups to identify which ones are not in use.

Alternatively, I wonder if you can just attempt to delete them? If they are "in use", the deletion should probably fail. (But test it first!)

Comment: All of my recommendation can be done in a few lines of code. Just use `describe_security_groups()` and `describe_network_interfaces()`. No manual work required.